# EmguCV Image size different from Image.Data size

Tags: c#, image, emgucv

I copy a part of an image to a new one:

```
bigImage.ROI = SomeRectangle;
Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Rgb, byte> roiImage = bigImage.Copy();
```

Now `roiImage.Cols==roiImage.Width==1` and `roiImage.Rows==roiImage.Height==106`; however size of `roiImage.Data` is `[106,4,3]`. So Width of image is not equal to the second dimension of the data.

Why does that occur?

Comment: Maybe that width is really the image stride, where the rows must be aligned to 4 bytes boundaries (increase with padding to nearest 4 byte).  Looks like `Emgu.CV.Image` contains an internal `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, what size does that report?

Comment: How are rows aligned? Appended to last or surrounded?

Comment: Padded at the end of each row, to match the requirements of various Windows API (like DIB format for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EmguCV requires each row of your image to be aligned by 4 bytes to improve efficiency in fetching data.